# When I enter my password on login screen it says sorry that didint work

Tags: password

How do I fix it or create a new account on logging screen

Comment: When the Capslock key is on, you'd get a warning, but not when the numlock key is on, and when you don't have a keypad, that may change the letters on the right side of the keyboard to numbers.

Comment: Did the password work before? Or is this your first login attempt?